# Вывод рекламного баннера на сайте?

Tags: php, html

Ребята подскажите как сделать, на сайте есть возможность выводить с админки обычные баннеры картинка + ссылка, но мне нужно сделать так что бы ещё можно было вставлять код рекламы яндекс + adsense то есть сделать поле для кода за основу можно взять например фаил вывода баннера.
За место поля ссылка сделать поле для вставки кода что бы он после сохранения показывался на сайте.

Код сюда не вставить если кто может помочь напишите пожалуйста

```
<? session_start(); 
require_once('../connect/connect.php'); 
include_once('../lib/lib.php'); 
require('pdk.php'); 

if ((isset($_POST["MM_insert"])) && ($_POST["MM_insert"] == "form")) 
{ $err=""; $opl_data=$_POST['opl_data']; $prim =_pre($_POST['prim']); 

 if(!$opl_data) $err .= 'Укажите, до какой даты оплачен блок<br>'; if(trim($_POST['rec_url'])) 
{ $dom=trim($_POST['rec_url']); $dom=strip_tags($dom); $dom=str_replace("'","",$dom); $dom=str_replace("`","",$dom); $dom=str_replace("\"","",$dom);

 if (strpos ($dom, "http:") === 0) 
     $pos=strpos ($dom, "http:")+7; 
 else $pos=0; 
     $dom=substr($dom, $pos, strlen($dom)-$pos); 
     $rec_url="https://".$dom; 
} 
 else 
     $rec_url=''; 
 if ($_FILES['fil']['tmp_name']) 
 { $ext = type_img($_FILES['fil']['type']); 
  if ($ext != ".gif" && $ext != ".jpg" && $ext != ".jpeg") 
      $err .= "Недопустимый формат файла. Допускаются только файлы в формате GIF, JPG<br>"; 
  $size_img = getimagesize($_FILES['fil']['tmp_name']); 
  $banner=$size_img[0]."_".$size_img[1]; } 
 else $err .= "Вы не загрузили баннер<br>"; 
 if ($err=="") 
 { mysql_query("INSERT INTO rec ( rec_url, rec_typ, banner, opl_data, opl, prim ) VALUES ( '".$rec_url."', '2', '".$banner."', '".$opl_data."', '1', '".$prim."' )"); 
  $ins=mysql_insert_id(); 
  if(!$err && $ins) 
  { 
      $ssmall='banner/'.$ins.$ext; 
      if(copy($_FILES['fil']['tmp_name'], $base_path.$ssmall)) 
      { 
          if($rec_url) $rec_cont='<a target=_blank rel="nofollow" href="'.$rec_url.'"><img border=0 src="'.dir_top().$ssmall.'"></a>'; 
          else $rec_cont='<img border=0 src="'.dir_top().$ssmall.'">'; 
          mysql_query("UPDATE rec SET rec_img='".$ssmall."', rec_cont='".$rec_cont."' WHERE id_rec='".$ins."'"); 
      } else { 
          mysql_query("DELETE FROM rec WHERE id_rec='".$ins."'"); } 
  } 
  echo "<HTML><HEAD><meta http-equiv='Refresh' content='0; URL=refresh.php?i=all_rec_user.php'></HEAD></HTML>"; 
  exit(); 
 } 
} 
$titl="Графический баннер GIF"; 
require ('top.php'); 
if($err) 
    echo "<p><font color=red>".$err."</font></p>"; ?> 
    <form enctype="multipart/form-data" name="form" method="post" action=""> 
        <table> 
            <tr> <td width="170">Ссылка</td> 
                 <td><input type="text" name="rec_url" size="60" value="<? echo $rec_url; ?>"></td> 
            </tr> 
            <tr> 
                <td>FILE</td> 
                <td><input type="file" name="fil" size="50"></td> 
            </tr> 
            <tr> 
                <td>Разместить до</td> 
                <td><input readonly="readonly" value="<?=$opl_data?>" name="opl_data" class="date-pick dp-applied"></td> 
            </tr> 
            <tr> 
                <td>Пометки администратора</td> 
                <td><textarea name="prim" rows="5" cols="61"><?=stripslashes(htmlspecialchars_decode($prim))?></textarea></td> 
            </tr> 
            <tr> 
                <td>&nbsp;</td> 
                <td>&nbsp;</td> 
            </tr> 
            <tr> 
                <td> <input type="submit" class="submit" name="Submit" value="Добавить"></td> 
                <td> <input type="hidden" name="MM_insert" value="form"> </td> 
            </tr> 
        </table>
</form> 
<? require('bottom.php'); ?>
```

---

Comment: Ну вроде это вписывается в самые основы php, что вы пытались сделать и какие проблемы у вас возникли?

Comment: Мне нужно за место поле ссылка сделать возможность туда добавлять код баннера.

Comment: Мне сюда код не добавить я бы показала его

Comment: Есть такая команда "echo" , используйте ее

Comment: Не знаю как  всеравно не добавить код сюда

Comment: Да хотя бы простым текстом можно вставить, дальше кто-нибудь сам отформатирует, поставив 4 пробела. Этот сайт отлично адаптирован для вставки кода

Comment: Не получается не текстом ни кавычками ни отступами он не даёт разместить постоянно красная табличка вылетает

Comment: Прочитайте то, что написано на табличке, и выполните её указания?

Comment: Я ставила эти ковычки бесполезно

Comment: Что там написано-то?

Comment: Кажется, ваше сообщение содержит код, не оформленный соответствующим образом. Пожалуйста, выделите весь код 4 отступами с помощью кнопки на панели инструментов или воспользуйтесь комбинацией клавиш CTRL+K. Чтобы получить дополнительную справку по редактированию, нажмите значок [?] в панели инструментов.

Comment: Ну вот, что вам помешало выделить код и нажать Ctrl+K?

Comment: Я с андроида да и толку если код целиком не входит

Comment: Расширение `mysql_*` давно мертво. Советую выбрать другой драйвер mysql.

Answer (score 2):

Попробую ответить

Вы привели код, который выводит форму администратора для добавления баннера по ссылке или как файл

Результатом работы этого кода будут записи в таблице `rec`:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO rec ( rec_url, rec_typ, banner, opl_data, opl, prim ) VALUES ( '".$rec_url."', '2', '".$banner."', '".$opl_data."', '1', '".$prim."' )");
```

Скорее всего, в этой таблице хранятся некие записи (загадка 1) для отображения где-то (загадка 2)

Судя по коду с загрузкой файла ниже в примере (я его отформатировал и добавил скобки, чтобы легче было понять, что происходит)

```
$ssmall='banner/'.$ins.$ext;
if ($rec_url) {
    $rec_cont='<a target=_blank rel="nofollow" href="'.$rec_url.'">
    <img border=0 src="'.dir_top().$ssmall.'">
    </a>';
} else {
    $rec_cont='<img border=0 src="'.dir_top().$ssmall.'">';
}
mysql_query("UPDATE rec SET
rec_img='".$ssmall."',
rec_cont='".$rec_cont."'
WHERE id_rec='".$ins."'");
```

в таблице есть еще 2 поля, очень важные для вашей задачи:

1. rec_img - это ссылка на изображение баннера, нам она не нужна вроде
2. rec_cont - это фактически код баннера, который скорее всего будет отображаться где-то (загадка 2)

Таким образом, вашу задачу *скорее всего* можно решить, если написать форму для добавления этих же записей, но указав код в поле записи `rec_cont` тот, который вам нужен (рекламный)

Загадки, которые нельзя разрешить только при помощи предвидения и телепатии:

**Загадка 1**. Что именно хранится в таблице rec, что это за записи и какие у них есть поля, какой смысл имеет каждое поле?

**Загадка 2**. Где код отображения баннеров? Как именно читаются данные из таблицы rec и как выводятся на странице? Какие там есть проверки и варианты вывода?

**Загадка 3**. Как именно составить запись в таблице rec, чтобы оно отобразилось так, как вам нужно?

Больше данных я не могу вынуть из заданного вопроса, но у меня нет диплома телепата. Просто стараюсь помочь чем могу

Чтобы определить, что именно вставлять в эту таблицу, надо еще выяснить формат рекламного блока и в каком виде он предоставляется. И разумеется обязательно надо знать то, как это выводится на страницах - баннеры рекламы бывают разных размеров, ведь мы не хотим, чтобы они разорвали нам верстку. Это уже не является загадкой, это просто подзадачи

Разрешив загадки, вы сможете решить свою задачу )) Представьте, что это квест

Удачи

UPD: Я просто взял ваш код и выбросил лишнее. Читайте комментарии. Я не гарантирую, что это будет работать в вашем случае, используйте код для изучения и как базу для доработок

```
<?
session_start();
require_once ('../connect/connect.php');
include_once ('../lib/lib.php');
require ('pdk.php');

if ((isset($_POST["MM_insert"])) && ($_POST["MM_insert"] == "form")) {
    $err = "";
    $opl_data = $_POST['opl_data'];
    $prim = _pre($_POST['prim']);
    if (!$opl_data) {
        $err .= 'Укажите, до какой даты оплачен блок<br>';
    }
    $rec_url = ''; // Это вроде бы ссылка href для баннера, попробуйте оставить пустой
    $banner = ''; // Тут должны быть какие-то размеры баннера, не знаю что писать
    $rec_cont = $_POST['rec_cont']; // Просто берем как есть весь код баннера
    if (strlen($rec_cont) == 0) {
        $err .= 'Укажите код рекламного баннера для размещения<br>';
    }
    if ($err == "") {
        // ВНИМАНИЕ! Настоятельно рекомендуется использовать расширение mysqli вместо mysql
        mysql_query("INSERT INTO rec (
        rec_url,
        rec_typ,
        rec_cont,
        banner,
        opl_data,
        opl,
        prim
        ) VALUES (
        '" . $rec_url . "',
        '2',
        '" . $rec_cont /* Зающая дырища безопасности, на живой базе выполняется присланный $_POST от пользователя */ . "',
        '" . $banner . "',
        '" . $opl_data . "',
        '1',
        '" . $prim . "'
        )");
        echo "<HTML><HEAD><meta http-equiv='Refresh' content='0; URL=refresh.php?i=all_rec_user.php'></HEAD></HTML>";
        exit();
    }
}
$titl = "Рекламный баннер";
require ('top.php');
if ($err)
    echo "<p><font color=red>" . $err . "</font></p>";
?>
<form name="form" method="post" action="">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td width="170">Код рекламного баннера</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="rec_cont" size="60" value="<? echo $rec_cont; ?>"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Разместить до</td>
            <td><input readonly="readonly" value="<?=$opl_data?>" name="opl_data" class="date-pick dp-applied"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Пометки администратора</td>
            <td><textarea name="prim" rows="5" cols="61"><?=stripslashes(htmlspecialchars_decode($prim))?></textarea></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="submit" class="submit" name="Submit" value="Добавить"></td>
            <td><input type="hidden" name="MM_insert" value="form"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
<? require('bottom.php'); ?>
```

Настоятельно рекомендую вам прочитать про [mysql_real_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php), и еще про [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.overview.php)

Comment: вот сама таблица rec фото https://ibb.co/kU5aM7

Comment: банер добавляется в админки и после сохранения нужно поставить галочку где он будет выводится  место 1 - под формой поиска 
место 2 - сбоку справа 
место 3 - после 4-го объявления 
место 4 - после 9-го объявления

Comment: Хорошо, и в чем у вас сложности сделать форму по примеру и сделать простой INSERT в эту таблицу? Попробуйте сначала просто через PHPMyAdmin вставить запись на в тестовом окружении, посмотрите, что из этого получится и что отобразиться в итоге. А потом уже и форму, по шажкам, за пару дней - вот POST, вот строка SQL, вот INSERT в базу. Не торопитесь, учитесь, это не просто, с наскока за 5 минут не сделаешь

Comment: Для ввода кода баннера лучше не input[type=text] использовать, а textarea, если будут проблемы с выводом, посмотрите на этот момент внимательнее, я что-то упустил это дело

Comment: попробовала все равно код банера не отображается на сайте

Comment: <td><textarea   size="60" value="<? echo $rec; ?>"></textarea></td>

Comment: Откуда $rec? Почему атрибут value? Наверное вы хотели написать `<td><textarea name="rec_cont"><? echo $rec_cont; ?></textarea></td>`, посмотрите описание элемента, пожалуйста: http://htmlbook.ru/html/Textarea

Comment: Само ничего не получится, @Люба, необходимо "грызть гранит науки". Судя по тому, как вы используете код php и html, и по двум вашим вопросам, вы пока в начале этого пути. Это хорошо, учитесь, спрашивайте, разбирайтесь

Comment: $rec выводит на странице сам баннер

Comment: А откуда $rec берется?

Comment: С базы данных там есть такая строка

Comment: Обновите вопрос. Я не вижу ни одной переменной с именем `$rec`, то есть код `<? echo $rec; ?>` ничего не выведет, но вы его используете. Значит либо код обновился относительно примера, либо вы не знаете, что такое переменные и как ими пользоваться